# Javascript syntax problems

Tags: javascript, asp.net, syntax

I am creating a new literal control from code behind, I add standard html into it which works fine. I try to add `<%= SomeDiv.ClientID %>` into this literal control but it quite literally prints into source exactly whats in code behind.

Code behind:

```
new LiteralControl("<div id='" + paneID.Replace(" ", "") + "_Expand' runat='server' onclick='ChangePanelHeader(&#39;<%= " + paneID.Replace(" ", "") + "_Expand.ClientID %>&#39;" + ", " + "&#39;<%= " + paneID.Replace(" ", "") + "_cpe.ClientID %>&#39;)' class='rhsCollapsiblePanelsHeader'>" + paneTitle + "<br /><br /></div>" + paneContent)
```

In Browser Source once page is loaded:

```
<div id='Tellafriend_Expand' runat='server' onclick='ChangePanelHeader(&#39;<%= Tellafriend_Expand.ClientID %>&#39;, &#39;<%= Tellafriend_cpe.ClientID %>&#39;)' class='rhsCollapsiblePanelsHeader'>Tell a friend<br /><br /></div>
```

Wanted result:

```
<div id='Tellafriend_Expand' runat='server' onclick='ChangePanelHeader("MyTelAFriendID_Expand", "MyTelAFriendID_cpe") class='rhsCollapsiblePanelsHeader'>Tell a friend<br /><br /></div>
```

Firefox syntax error:

```
syntax error
[Break On This Error]   

ChangePanelHeader(<%= Tellafriend_Expand.ClientID %>, <%= Tellafriend_cpe.Cli...

default.aspx (line 1, col 20)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(After my initial "Huh?") I notice you're getting your server-side code to output ids that are not wrapped in quotes. In JS those ids likely need to be treated as strings, so try this:

```
ChangePanelHeader("<%= Tellafriend_Expand.ClientID %>", ...);
// add quotes ----^----------------------------------^
```

(If that's not it, well, I'll wait for the question rewrite promised in your comment.)

Comment: Thanks mate, sorry its 3 am in the morning in the uk. I have rewritten it let me know if you require anything else.

Comment: You've embedded the `<%=` within your server-side string literals, so that's why it all ends up in the source the browser sees. I haven't really done anything with ASP code-behind so I'm not sure how to achieve the effect you want - I gather you want to dynamically generate the name of an object and then get the `.ClientID` of that object?

Comment: Yep I have just noticed I can get it in code behind using Object.ClientID I will see what this produces

Comment: Instead of `<%= object.ClientID %>` you can just do `Object.ClientID` in code behind, also in stead of `&#39;` i just did `\"` I should of been escaping characters from the start.

Comment: I nearly updated my answer to suggest exactly that, but it looked to me like you were building the name of the object by taking the string from `paneID.Replace()` and adding `"_expand"` on the end, and I wasn't sure about how to deal with that part.